# base_url is not being parsed by EE

Tags: template-partials

Is there a reason {base_url} is not being parsed at all in any of my templates?

First I thought it was only my css but it also seems not to be working with any other template either like image roots?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using {site_url} instead.

Comment: That's really strange, I wonder why that works and not base?

Comment: Pretty sure base_url is for creating custom urls in the control panel, not in a template.

Comment: That’s could explain it, but in a previous core install I was using it in the my css file and it worked.